# jQuery select one main option or multiple sub option from same main option using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Nazem/7f6yp29s/)

Here, i wanted to **Select only 1 Main Option**. i.e

1. If there is no sub section, i may select only one main option like **Bond** or **Market**. If one main option is checked, other main or sub option will be unchecked.
2. If there are sub sections, i may select one or more sub-option from same main option, but not from different main option. And same as before, other main options and sub options from other main options will be unchecked. 
   Such as, if i select **Commodity**, i can select **Natural** too, because both of these are under **Commodities**. But if i click another *sub option* like **Celeb** or *main option* like **Market**, which is not under **Commodities**, then both **Commodity** & **Natural** will be unchecked.

my **HTML:**

```
<div class="topic-search">
<ul class=" topic-dropdown-menu">
   <li class="topic-search-mainmenu" id="" data-topic="Bond">
      <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="BOND" value=''>Bond
   </li>

   <li class="topic-search-dropdown-submenu">
      <p class="topic-open">Commodities <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></p>
      <ul class="topic-search-submenu">
         <li class="topic-search-submenu-mainmenu" data-topic="Commodities">
            <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="CMMD" value=''>Commodity
         </li>
         <li class="topic-search-submenu-mainmenu" data-topic="Commodities">
            <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="NTRL" value=''>Natural
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="topic-search-mainmenu" data-topic="Market" >
      <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="MRKT" value=''>Market
   </li>

   <li class="topic-search-dropdown-submenu">
      <p class="topic-open">Entertainment <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></p>
      <ul class="topic-search-submenu">
         <li class="topic-search-submenu-mainmenu" data-topic="Gas">
            <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="CMD" value=''>Celeb
         </li>
         <li class="topic-search-submenu-mainmenu" data-topic="Gas">
            <input type='checkbox' name='topics[]' class='ticker-menu' id="GAS" value=''>Public Gossip
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>


</ul>
</div>
```

my **jQuery:**

```
var ticker_menu = $("input.ticker-menu");
var parent_data_topic_name = "";

ticker_menu.on('click', function() {
   // $(this).prop('checked', true);
   if(parent_data_topic_name ==""){
        parent_data_topic_name = $(this).parent().attr('data-topic');
      ticker_menu.not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   }
   else{
       parent_data_topic_name = $(this).parent().attr('data-topic');

     ticker_menu.each(function( e ) {

        if(ticker_menu.not(this).is(':checked') && ticker_menu.parent().attr('data-topic') == parent_data_topic_name){

        var id_name = ticker_menu.not(this).attr('id');

        $(""+id_name).prop('checked', true); 
     }else{

        var id_nam = ticker_menu.not(this).attr('id');

       $(""+id_name).prop('checked', false);
     }   

     });


   }


});
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is I hope what you were looking for.

I strongly advise you to have a look at [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) which is different to the css selector :not

```
$('.topic-search-mainmenu [type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.topic-search-mainmenu [type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        this.checked = false
    })
    this.checked = true
})

$('.topic-search-dropdown-submenu [type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.topic-search-dropdown-submenu [type="checkbox"]').not($(this).parents('.topic-search-submenu').find('[type="checkbox"]')).each(function(){
        this.checked = false
    })
})
```

This is your updated **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f6yp29s/4/)**

Comment: You were very close. Thanks :) I have used your logic. Now it's working. Hope You will understand what i was trying to do. Many Many Thanks for your help :)  this is the updated fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nazem/nz9yw81o/)

Comment: @NazemMahmud If it's orrect could you pls accept my answer :)

Comment: It was almost correct. That's why i gave it an upvote. whatever, i am accepting this. this was a great help, thanks :)